# How to pass a variable value from one page to other using POST in drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a `register` page which saves some data into the database and after completion of this form I have redirected it to a `success` page.But I would like to pass a `variable value` to the next page.I was using `drupal_goto` but it appends the value in the `url`,which is not what I need. And I have been using `$_SESSION`,but sometime I find it confusing. I can't retrieve the value in some cases. Could someone help me with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

With the Drupal API:

```
drupal_goto($path = '', $query = NULL, $fragment = NULL, $http_response_code = 302)
```

**$path:** (optional) A Drupal path or a full URL, which will be passed to url() to compute the redirect for the URL.

**$query:** (optional) A URL-encoded query string to append to the link, or an array of query key/value-pairs without any URL-encoding. Passed to url().

**$fragment:** (optional) A destination fragment identifier (named anchor).

**$http_response_code:** (optional) The HTTP status code to use for the redirection, defaults to 302.

Comment: tanx for the reply @Alexandre.but i do not want the string to be appended in the url....

Comment: in drupal_goto if i have use this function as drupal_goto("my_page", "value1=1&value2=2"); the url i wil be getting will be http://mysite.com/my_page?value1=1&value2=2 .. i want just http://mysite.com/my_page but also i need to pass this variable in a $_POST manner..

Answer (score 0):

With POST and form_redirect:

```
function page_1_form_submit($form, &$form_state)
{
  $data_a = $form_state['values']['data_a_form'];
  $data_b = $form_state['values']['data_b_form'];

  $options = array(
  'query' => array(
     'data_a' => $data_a,
     'data_b' => $data_b,
    )
  );

  $form_state['redirect'] = array('url_page2', $options);
}
```